# Paste within line in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I started to use *macvim* not only for code, but also for editing a wiki and academic writing in LaTeX. After several honeymoon moments ;-) and first customization efforts, I found a problem I can't solve:

How do I paste content from the system clipboard *within* a line, no matter where this content is copied from? (I use LaunchBar’s multi clipboard feature quite excessively and store mostly > 20 strings from different applications I will paste sooner or later. It works well with macvim, but not when it comes to "linewise" content.) p or P create newlines, cmd-v as well.

I neither want to add strings [between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287031/how-to-paste-something-between-html-tags-in-vim?rq=1), nor focus on other specialised settings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how Launchbar works in this regard but all the clipboard managers I've used send a `Cmd-v` when you hit `Enter`.

MacVim, being very well integrated in the system, supports many default Mac OS X shortcuts like `Cmd-o`, `Cmd-s` or `Cmd-v` so… simply selecting the item in Launchbar's list and hitting `Enter` should work.

If your pasted content ends up on a line of its own (presumably above the current line) instead of in the middle of your sentence that means that the pasted text contains a new line, plain and simple. Because MacVim maps `Cmd-v` to `P`, the pasted content is pasted before the cursor: inline if there's no newline in sight, above the current line if there are newlines.

That's normal behavior.

At that point, either you find a way to clean Launchbar's content up before `Cmd-v` or you edit the pasted text afterward with something like `^v$y"_d<movement>P`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> only create new lines if the clipboard contains a newline character.

I just pasted `one-line content` from my clipboard into vim and it worked fine (in-line).

The issue may be with the way LaunchBar is copying to its clipboards.